# Image OCR Android

Tags: android, image, ocr

I am working on an android application in which I have to perform OCR from an Image. For example if I have drawing of building, user clicks on a particular area on the image (like Kitchen or Parking lot), after that click I want the location name/number where the user have clicked. This number will be present in that location. [image]

in the given image if i click on Lecture Room part then the application must detect the area where I have clicked and give me the name (i.e. Lecture Room) for further queries..

Please help me out. I have tested many applications but most of them detects words not the drawing images.

**Edit**
It is just like HTML Image Maping

Comment: I am stuck on something similar. Did you find a solution? Would be great if you could reply. Thanks. :)

Comment: I changed the approach later.. Its been long now..

Comment: I know that it has been long and that is why I appreciate you replying back. I am doing nothing fancy. No images. Only normal text ocr.  Just wanted to know which library/approach you used..?

Comment: this link may help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533273/best-ocr-optical-character-recognition-example-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Interesting project, I've been developing an Android app with OCR and I included useful information and a code example in the next post, have a look at it and if you have any question, just ping me:

https://solidgeargroup.com/ocr-on-android

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you need to work on how you have abstracted your problem, if the goal of the application is to read any image file and extract all the text from it in order to make it searchable, you've got quite a project ahead of you.

However, if your goal is to make a finite number of maps clickable, I'd say that you should create a table of all the known locations in each image and then save the coordinate where the user clicked. That way you can look up that coordinate in your table of known locations and present the corresponding room to the user. A room could for instance be defined by the coordinates of its northwest corner and its southeast corner. Determining whether or not a coordinate is within those boundaries is trivial.

If your application really requires OCR you are in a world of trouble I'm afraid.

Edit: minor mistakes edited out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..But I am afraid, I have to perform OCR, because maps can be infinite or changing frequently...