# best OCR (Optical character recognition) example in android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I want a running example of OCR in android, I have done some research and find an example that implements OCR in android.

https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two and in it there are three projects files...

1. eyes-two
2. tess-two
3. tess-two-test

I have executed the "tess-two-test" project by importing the three project files but "tess-two-test" does not include any activities so it will not run.

Can anybody suggest me a better example?

Comment: https://github.com/komamitsu/Android-OCRSample

Comment: Have a look at this [similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17722274/1051783).

Comment: Hi Komal, you're question is very useful and needs to be reopened. Why don't you change the title something like "OCR example in android", add little bit info where you got the problem and change the question in the end like "anyone knows how to solve this?" then I think it'll be good to be reopened.

Comment: Simple example done by me https://github.com/bieliaievays/Tess-two_example

Comment: Google recently released an OCR API: https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Like you I also faced many problems implementing OCR in Android, but after much Googling I found the solution, and it surely is the best example of OCR.

Let me explain using step-by-step guidance.

First, download the source code from https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two.

Import all three projects. After importing you will get an error.
To solve the error you have to create a `res` folder in the tess-two project

[image]

First, just create **res** folder in tess-two by tess-two->RightClick->new Folder->Name it "res"

After doing this in all three project the error should be gone.

Now download the source code from https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr, here you will get best example.

Now you just need to import it into your workspace, but first you have to download android-ndk from this site:

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html i have windows 7 - 32 bit PC so I have download http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-windows-x86.zip this file

Now extract it suppose I have extract it into **E:\Software\android-ndk-r9** so I will set this path on Environment Variable

Right Click on **MyComputer->Property->Advance-System-Settings->Advance->Environment Variable->** find **PATH** on second below Box and set like path like below picture

[image]

done it

Now open cmd and go to on D:\Android Workspace\tess-two 
like below

[image]

If you have successfully set up environment variable of NDK then just type **ndk-build** just like above picture than enter you will not get any kind of error and all file will be compiled successfully:

Now download other source code also from https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two , and extract and import it and give it name OCRTest, like in my PC which is in **D:\Android Workspace\OCRTest**

[image]

Import test-two in this and run OCRTest and run it; you will get the best example of OCR.

Comment: Thank you so much Siddhpura Amit, This is the best example... i have used it and it is running successfully

Comment: @Siddhpura I am getting the following error  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.initOcrEngine(CaptureActivity.java:711)

Comment: Nice one @Siddhpura Amit

Comment: @Shink I got the same error, how did you resolve it?

Comment: hi i have successfully configured the project , but with OCRTest app while capturing and returned string is not correct plz help me ....

Comment: Does it not returning English string or converted string???

Comment: @NehaShukla If English string is that showing in first left side corner?

Comment: I vote up only one time because I cannot vote up many times.

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit I am trying to create the "res" folder but it says the already exists one

Comment: Can I start it from an external app?
Like zxing barcode: Intent i = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); and get the result in data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT")

Comment: I created an issue https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr/issues/38

Comment: android studio download ndk and we can download from there too is it is the same things or different ??

Comment: I am getting this errro when i run OCR TEST java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example