# Get text details From the Image in Android

Tags: android, image-processing

How to get text Details from the image(Like :Any Card) in Android
is there any way For Getting ??
Then Please Help Me

Comment: Anycard? What is that? Could you just elaborate.

Comment: You can use OCR Library. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19533854/1405983

Comment: Any Card Mean Capture of ATM card or image of Identity card etc..

Comment: I want to create an application like take image of any card and get information of the card and show this in my application

Comment: Check for tesseract-ocr. It is an opensource library.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OCR library for this.

```
1.Look at ABBYY's Android OCR lib (paid)

2.Tesseract JNI wrapper (free)  as this is written in c .you should use as ndk in android
```

Answer (score 0):

Following steps to get the text data from any printed text area/ card/ paper using camera capture image.

1) Download open source tess-two library from [Tessract library](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list)

2) Download sample OcrTest project from [OcrTest project](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr)

3)Download [tesseract-ocr-3.01.osd.tar.gz](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list) file and make into tesseract-ocr-3.01.osd.tar.zip file( 3.01 is version number you can download latest version) and download [osd.trainned.zip](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/trunk/tessdata/osd.traineddata?r=540&spec=svn540) file and paste into asset folder. the after run the project.

(Note: JNI build path configure the your eclipse, for more details for Jni configaraton [click here](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/ndk-builder-in-eclipse/).