# Is this possible to use google translate api in android?

Tags: android, ocr

> i need an image to text conversion using OCR.so i used a code [from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533273/best-ocr-optical-character-recognition-example-in-android)
>
> and its working fine, but its not converting exact values.
>
> so is there any other library file better than this?? or it is possible to use Google translate API? or Google OCR API?
>
> i am struggling on this please suggest me any good tutorial link or any suggestion to over come this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by exact values? Do you need higher accuracy?

Comment: yes @Vitalik the same values i need

Answer (score 1):

2 years late, but have you tried [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr) OCR? It is open source