# digit detection from the image in android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am searching for how to extract a digital number from the image in android. I have to take a picture then i need to get numbers from image. OpenCV is a option . can we convert opencv into android ? Kindly suggest me any proper way. I will be grateful to you.

Comment: what is the actual requirement ?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533273/best-ocr-optical-character-recognition-example-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many OCR for Android
check there links

1. https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr
2. https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR
3. http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/android/
4. [best OCR (Optical character recognition) example in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533273/best-ocr-optical-character-recognition-example-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV supports Android platform. You have to set up OpenCV4Android, it's instructions step by step here.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html

However OpenCV is not an option but only a step. Then you have to use a character recognition engine. Most popular one is Tesseract-ocr. But it is really not easy task.

Also, they often recognize all characters. If you could achieve it, extracting the digits will be the easiest part in Java.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me you just need to specify the number size` ArrayList output=new ArrayList<>();

```
    cvtColor(input,input,COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);


    Mat img_threshold = new Mat();
    threshold(input, img_threshold, 60, 255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    Mat img_contours =copy(img_threshold);
    //Find contours of possibles characters


    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    findContours(img_contours, contours,new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE); // all pixels of each contours
    contours=sort(contours);


    // Draw blue contours on a white image
    Mat result=copy(img_threshold);
    cvtColor(result, result, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    drawContours(result,contours,
            -1, // draw all contours
            new Scalar(0,0,255), // in blue
            1); // with a thickness of 1


    //Start to iterate to each contour founded
    ListIterator<MatOfPoint> itc = contours.listIterator();

    //Remove patch that are no inside limits of aspect ratio and area.
    while (itc.hasNext())
    {
        //Create bounding rect of object
        MatOfPoint mp = new MatOfPoint(itc.next().toArray());
        Rect mr = boundingRect(mp);
        rectangle(result,new Point(mr.x,mr.y),new Point(mr.x+mr.width,mr.y+mr.height),new Scalar(0,255,0));

        Mat auxRoi=new Mat(img_threshold,mr);


        if (OCR_verifySizes(auxRoi))
        {
            output.add(preprocessChar(auxRoi));
        }
    }

    return output;`
```