# Read correct OCR data(having less accuracy) using Tesseract

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

Hi I have to develope an application to read OCR data .

After  Googling I found that i can achieve it using Tesseract .

I got Tesseract source code from https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two

I got its libraries by donloading NDK from http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-windows-x86.zip

Now extracted it suppose I have extract it into E:\Software\android-ndk-r9 so I will set this path on Environment Variable

Right Click on MyComputer->Property->Advance-System-Settings->Advance->Environment Variable-> find PATH on second below Box and set like path like below picture

[image]

Now open  cmd and go to on D:\Android Workspace\tess-two like below

[image]

Now downloaded other source code also from https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two , and extract and import it and give it name OCRTest, like in my PC which is in D:\Android Workspace\OCRTest

[image]

So I have compile both two projects successfully by taking help from [best OCR (Optical character recognition) example in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533273/best-ocr-optical-character-recognition-example-in-android)

But my problem is when I click on capture button then it is producing wrong text .

If anyone had done this correctly then please help me...

Thanks a lot in advance....

Comment: hey I have already mentioned that i got help from this answer in that question but my problem is another. I am not able to read correct data .....

Comment: do check [abbyy OCR](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/tree/master/Android) its better accuracy than Tesseract

Comment: hey have you worked with OCR reading

Comment: then plz help me how can i solved it

Comment: I already told ...... u need a free api ? ... If yes then it may not give accurate results... Abbyy is paid api.

Comment: thanks let me check it...

Comment: okkk and does it also provide auto capture of OCR data

Comment: u can use images from the gallery or capture live documents via camera.. r u asking the same ?

Comment: hii i have downloaded sample demo app but getting unauthorized.. what i have to put in app i and password

Comment: do signup on https://cloud.ocrsdk.com/Account/Register

Comment: hey yess its giving more accurate that Tesseract but can u tell me paid api of Abbyysdk is purely accurate or not..

Answer (score 1):

Do check [abbyy OCR](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/tree/master/Android) its better accuracy than Tesseract

```
ABBYY offers its compact OCR Engine for Android
The latest Android smart phones have
    * good auto focus cameras and
    * more than 3 megapixel
    * so they are perfectly equipped to take sharp pictures of documents that contain textual information.
Implementing OCR on Android based applications can turn the phone in a information/text capture device. The data can be
    * processed directly on the phone, for example add a new contact to the address book
    * sent to a sever to get more information
    * sent to a text to speech engine
    * sent to a translation service

New in V4 R5: Java Native Interface Wrapper (JNIWrapper) is included!
New in V4 R7: Barcode Recognition is included!
```

[image]

Pricing Details http://ocrsdk.com/plans-and-pricing/

for more --> http://www.abbyy-developers.eu/en:mobile-imaging-sdk:start

Comment: i have to read passport data so i need that it can auto capture passport details ,, do u have any idea about it that abbyysdk provide this feature or not

Comment: seems to be http://www.abbyy.com/mobile_imaging_sdk/scenarios/  ... do u found this answer useful ... if so then accept and do upvote :)

Comment: yes i have upvoted.. will accept as well once my problem is resolved :)