# ocr tutorial ndk-build command error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am following this tutorial for OCR implementation in my project and i went step by step .

[best OCR (Optical character recognition) example in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533273/best-ocr-optical-character-recognition-example-in-android)

I set the path of the ndk in environment system variables as suggested. When i run the command ndk-build when going to tess-tw directory from command prompt, i am getting following error :

> C:\Users\manpsing>cd eclipsework
>
> C:\Users\manpsing\eclipsework>cd tess-two
>
> C:\Users\manpsing\eclipsework\tess-two>ndk-build [armeabi] Compile
>   : jpgt <= jaricom.c process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL,
>   C:/64Software/android-ndk-r11b/build//../tool
>   chains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androidea bi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jpgt/jaricom.o.d
>   -Ijni/libjpeg -DAN DROID -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -isystem C:/64Software/ android-ndk-r11b/build//../platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include -c
>   jni/libjp eg/jaricom.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jpgt/jaricom.o,
>   ...) failed. make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
>   make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/jpgt/jaricom.o] Error 2
>
> C:\Users\manpsing\eclipsework\tess-two>

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NDK r10e instead of r11.

reference:
https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/issues/152