# Android : How to capture text from camera without taking picture?

Tags: android, ocr

I want to capture texts and numbers that showing with camera without taking picture using tess-two(in android and eclipse).
I dont want to save image file.

something like this (it is capturing live on camera):

[image: OCR]

I have used tess-two , but i have to take picture first and then capture text.
(using link : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533273/best-ocr-optical-character-recognition-example-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533273/best-ocr-optical-character-recognition-example-in-android.))

and I have used this (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/840623/Android-Character-Recognition) to create behaviour like picture I have uploaded but it should take picture too.

so how can I achieve that?Is it possible?

Comment: Of course. Use the camera api. You will get a stream of pictures which you can handle as you wish. No need to save them to file.

Comment: Is tess forcing you 'to take a picture first'? What ever you mean with 'taking picture'. Can tess only read from file? Is that what you want to say? Not from a bitmap or so? Please be clear.

Comment: tess want bitmap just.

Comment: Well then my first comment comes true.

Comment: Try https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr

Comment: with camera preview callback

Comment: I think you can do this simpler and better using firebase ml

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bitmap of the thumbnail easily as given in the android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) but from your question it seems like you will need the full size picture bitmap, so to get the full size bitmap you have to point the camera to some file where the capture picture can be stored.

To get the full size bitmap try this

```
private String imagePath = "";

private void startCamera() {
    // create a collision-resistant file name
    String fileUniqueName= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = fileUniqueName + ".jpg";

    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    imagePath = storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageFileName;
    File file = new File(imagePath);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Intent cameraIntent = new     Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);               
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
}
```

Handle the captured image

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        File tempFile = new  File(imagePath);
        if(tempFile.exists()){        
            Bitmap requiredBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

This captured image will not be shown in the gallery.

Comment: This would not allow to see the image in real time

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use free SDK that does OCR without taking any picture: [ABBYY Real-time Recognition SDK](http://rtrsdk.com). It does all the work for manitulating video stream for you.

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY.

Comment: dose it need internet? I mean I have to be conneted to the internet for using it?

Answer (score 0):

```
/* this is the code of main activity it will capture text without taking picture all you need to do is to make a text field in mainActivity.xml */
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

> Blockquote

    import android.util.Log;
    import android.util.SparseArray;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
    import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
    import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
    import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        SurfaceView cameraView;
        TextView textView;
        CameraSource cameraSource;
        final int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case RequestCameraPermissionID:
                {
                    if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            return;
                        }
                        try {
                            cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

            TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
            if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
                Log.w("MainActivity", "Detector dependencies are not yet available");
            } else {
                cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                        .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                        .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                        .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                        .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                        .build();
                cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                        try {
                            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                       new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                       RequestCameraPermissionID);
                                return;
                            }
                            cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                        cameraSource.stop();
                    }
                });

                textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
                    @Override
                    public void release() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
                        final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
                        if(items.size()!=0){
                            textView.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
                                    for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
                                        TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                                        stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                                        stringBuilder.append("\n");
                                    }
                                    textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please could you add a few lines explaining your answer.

Comment: this is code of main activity it will capture the text.

Comment: hi bro @shouzebhasan can u send me sample project? i am interested in your code.

Comment: sure email me at shouzebhasan99@gmail.com